# Pandas pivot with specified (additional) columns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have a two different list of tuples that are converted into a pandas dataframe:

```
ls1 = [(1,"A",2),(1,"B",1),(1,"C",3),(2,"A",4),(2,"B",4,),(2,"C",5)]
ls2 = [(1,"A",2),(1,"C",3),(1,"B",1),(1,"D",6),(2,"A",4),(2,"C",5),(2,"B",4,)]
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(ls1, columns=['ID', 'Class', 'count'])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(ls2, columns=['ID', 'Class', 'count'])
```

Now I'd like to make a pivot table from both dataframes with the column names for the classes "A", "B", "C", "D". So, all four column names (if possible also in a specified order) should exist in the resulting pivot table. If there are no counts for a ID-Class combination these should be filled with e.g. NaN.

```
dfpivot1 = df1.pivot(index='ID', columns='Class', values='count')
dfpivot2 = df2.pivot(index='ID', columns='Class', values='count')

>>> dfpivot1
Class  A  B  C
ID            
1      2  1  3
2      4  4  5
>>>
```

Using the `.pivot` from pandas provides a pivot table for `df1`, but with only three Class-columns ("A","B","C"). So, `dfpivot1` needs to be modified to have the columns "A","B","C" AND "D" and thus, exactly match the columns of `dfpivot2`. As I am starting from a list of tuples also other approaches (without using `pandas`) might be interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need add [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html) or [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for fill `NaN`s for all missing columns:

```
cols = ['A','B','C','D']
dfpivot1 = df1.pivot(index='ID', columns='Class', values='count').reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
print (dfpivot1)
Class  A  B  C   D
ID                
1      2  1  3 NaN
2      4  4  5 NaN
```

Also is possible specify `fill_value` parameter:

```
cols = ['A','B','C','D']
dfpivot1 = df1.pivot(index='ID', columns='Class', values='count')
              .reindex_axis(cols, fill_value=0, axis=1)
print (dfpivot1)
Class  A  B  C  D
ID               
1      2  1  3  0
2      4  4  5  0
```

---

```
cols = ['A','B','C','D']
dfpivot1 = df1.pivot(index='ID', columns='Class', values='count').reindex(columns=cols)
print (dfpivot1)
Class  A  B  C   D
ID                
1      2  1  3 NaN
2      4  4  5 NaN
```